# VC++ undeclared indentifier 2005

Tags: visual-c++

Currently I am working on a migration project from visual c++ 6.0 to visual studio c++ 2005.
And during compilation, I am getting "Undeclared Identifier Error"

**code**

```
while(TRUE)
{       sEntry.Format(sActiveMbfs, ixR++);
        sProfile=pApp->GetProfileString(pszSection, sEntry, &afxChNil);
        if(!sProfile.GetLength())
        break;
```

**error**

> 1>c:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx.cpp(887) : error C2065: 'afxChNil' :
>   undeclared identifier

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Just pass `NULL` or the last parameter, or omit it entirely (`NULL` is the default for it).

Comment: Hi Igor,

I tried with NULL and omitting entire '&afxChNil' , but i didn't work.

could you please suggest.

Comment: Define "didn't work". What outcome did you expect, what did you observe, and how do the two differ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/23c07806-760e-414f-b86f-59205625f6ae/error-c2065-afxchnil-undeclared-identifier-when-vc6-to-vc-2003-convertion?forum=vclanguage), just replacing `&afxChNil` with either an empty string (`_T("")`) or `NULL` should do the trick.